# Filtering only some rows in a column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I have a df below:

```
name|
Bob
3245
Chris
Amy
Chris
3242424
Amy
```

If I want to filer for only amy but keep all rows that have numbers as well how can I do that?

Basically filter for all rows that have text to be amy but also include all other rows that are not names but the numbers as well?

Output:

```
name|
3245
Amy
3242424
Amy
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `.str.match`:

```
df[df['name'].str.match('Amy').fillna(True) ]
```

Or you can try your logic:

```
mask = df['name'].eq('Amy') | df['name'].astype(str).str.isnumeric()
df[mask]
```

Output:

```
      name
1     3245
3      Amy
5  3242424
6      Amy
```

Comment: when I try I only get back amy and not the rows with numbers in name col

Comment: both solutions only return the text name of amy not numbers - is this because that column is a object Dtype>? @Quang Hoang

Comment: Hi, sorry no I meant the column is dtype object, but still the output returned is only the amy rows not all other rows where it is 424242 or 256452 I dont understand @Quang Hoang

Comment: @Chris90 do `df.to_dict()` and post the output to your question.

Comment: I want all rows that are amy or any other that is the number - not names, i tried the code above and retrives only amy name

Comment: when I try to_dict it shows only amy under name column values

Comment: there is too many rows it will not show all the vlaues like numbers

Comment: i dont know how to better explaion my question sorry

Comment: `df.head(10).to_dict()`.

Comment: wait it works, not sure waht was going on before your mask method works thank u